# Can not switch from en_US.US-ASCII to en_US.UTF8

Tags: opensuse, locale

I am using many non ASCII characters in my filenames and up untill now everyone worked correctly. I am running **openSUSE Tumbleweed** and currently updated to the **20191118**.

I have noticed that my `locale` output is now showing

```
LANG=en_US.US-ASCII
LC_CTYPE="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_PAPER="C"
LC_NAME="C"
LC_ADDRESS="C"
LC_TELEPHONE="C"
LC_MEASUREMENT="C"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="C"
LC_ALL=C
```

I have tried to change settings by using `localectl set-locale LANG="en_US.utf-8"` but no success, since after the update they seem to reset.

I am not sure whether this is an actual bug somewhere (in Dolphin, KDE / Plasma, openSUSE, etc.) or some settings have changed?

Answer (score 0):

In case of not working the command that you have typed, you should search the locale file of Suse and edit it manyally:

In Debian based systems is:

```
/etc/default/locale
```

in Red Hat based and Suse the modification should be made in:

```
/etc/locale.conf
```

Moreover, have you restarted the system after applying the change?

If you do not have restarted it and you prefer to avoid the reboot, you can also change the locale by this way:

```
LANG="en_US.utf8"
export LANG
```

Another method to reconfigure the locale would be:

```
dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

Comment: Well I have checked `/etc/locale.conf` and it says `LANG=en_US.utf-8` so I guess that is correct. I also restarted but no effect.

Comment: Added a change with a new command: `dpkg-reconfigure locales`; that one should affect to LANG and also to the other sub-parameters

Comment: Not sure whether it is related but e.g. **~/.config/plasma-locale-settings.sh** seems to be setting all **LC_*** to ***.US-ASCII** but since my issue is that in the Dolphin I can see characters like � instead of real UTF-8 chars, it just might be.

Comment: You can also use locale-gen command to re-generate all the locales again to be sure